# On a network, using VBA how to find the machine where a file is open

Tags: vba, lan

Sometimes I need to open a file that is already open, and I would like to close it.
However before I close it, I would like to go to that machine and see what is happening with the file (is it active or not)
For that I need to know which machine on the network has it open.

How would I do that in VBA?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To close files, you don't need to know what machine on the network has it open.  What gave you that idea?  What method are you thinking of using to force the file closed?

For example, the 'openfiles' cmd, which closes open files, (executed by running a command shell), does not require the machine from which the file is held open: only the network path to the file (the machine on which the file is stored).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/openfiles

script example:

```
"cmd /k Openfiles /disconnect /S " & myServerName & " /U Administrator /P " & myPassword & " /ID "
```

Comment: Well, here is why: The file might be in in a process (read or write), so I would need to switch to the machine and first see what is going on with the file before I close it

Comment: @Robert If you wish to ask a different question, you may edit your question or ask a new question.